# perl static constant hashrefs

Tags: perl, static, constants, hashref

Is it possible to declare static constant hashrefs in perl?
I tried it with Readonly and Const::Fast module in the following way, but get the error message "Attempt to reassign a readonly variable" when I call the sub multiple times.

```
use Const::Fast;
use feature 'state';

sub test {
  const state $h => {1 => 1};
  #...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` is a function, and you're calling it every time `test` is called. This should do the trick.

```
sub test {
   state $h;
   state $initialized;
   const $h => ... if !$initialized++;
   # ...
}
```

Since `$h` always has a true value, we can use the following:

```
sub test {
   state $h;
   const $h => ... if !$h;
   # ...
}
```

Of course, you can still use the old way of doing persistent lexically-scoped variables.

```
{
   const my $h => ...;

   sub test {
      # ...
   }
}
```